# символьная ссылка и настройка версия php через консоль

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

**Что я хотел сделать**:

поменять в консоли версию по умолчанию из 7,0 на 5,6

**Какую команду консоли я использовал**:

```
sudo ln -sfn /etc/alternatives/php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

**Версию до команды выводило**:

```
php5.6 -v => PHP 5.6.26-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli)
```

**Версию которую стало выводить после команды**:

```
php5.6 -v => PHP 7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
```

**Версию которую стало выводить после команды**:

```
php -v => PHP 7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
```

***У меня есть два вопроса:***

1. как сделать чтобы `php -v` выводило версию 5,6
2. как сделать чтобы `php5.6 -v`  тоже выводило версию 5,6

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы сделали `/usr/bin/php5.6` ссылкой на `/etc/alternatives/php`. Так что первым делом необходимо вернуть ссылку на PHP 5.6 командой `sudo ln -sfn /path/to/php_5.6/bin/php /usr/bin/php5.6`, подставив нужный путь.
2. Для выбора версий используйте команду `update-alternatives --config php`.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как найти нужный путь. когда я ввожу whereis php | grep php выводит много вариантов http://pastebin.com/sf35KnNF

Comment: я похоже что скосил сам бинарник, я удалил вообще все пакеты пхп и установил по новой нужную мне, единую версию